# How to change default indexPath 0 to 1 of tableView in swift3?

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to display my data in tableView but I want to start indexPath from 1. But I am not getting any solution .Is there any way I can start indexPath from 1

output I am getting is:

**myData 1,2,3,4,5   and indexPath is 0,1,2,3,4**

what I want :

**myData 1,2,3,4,5   and indexPath is 1,2,3,4,5**

because of indexPath start from 0 my data at index 1 get assigned to 0 and so on.

CAN WE INCREMENT indexPath.row by one before loop starts

Comment: just a thought, but have you tried using 'indexPath + 1' ?

Comment: Do not add item at index 0 and when you are printing them (outputting, display whatever you are doing), skip index 0.

Comment: No bro. I have tried that it doesn't work!

Comment: @CodingYoshi how can I skip that first index 0 from indexPath

Comment: if you have an array, add a dummy item at index 0. Now you know you do not want that item so whenever you access the items from the array, start at index 1.

Comment: Sorry bro but I am using range array so I cannot add any dummy item!

Comment: Face the fact that in almost all computer languages indices are zero-based. The **first** index path has the index **zero**. Deal with it.

Comment: CAN WE INCREMENT indexPath.row by one before loop starts

Comment: Rather than *incrementing* the index path consider to *decrement* your data index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response but I get the solution for this

Here is the solution:

```
mainArrayRoll.insert("0", at: 0)
```

I have added an default value to my array so every time indexPath start from zero it deals with my default value and I get my proper output from index location 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change indexPath but you can display data as below  func

```
        let lblTitle: UILabel? = (cell?.viewWithTag(102) as? UILabel)
        lblTitle?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)" // here you need to add 1
```

Comment: Thank You for replay bro but I want to loop the indexPath and bcz it is starting from 0 it is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

[IndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath) uses arrays which start at index `0`.

> Each index in an index path represents the index into an array of children

Comment: Did the OP ask what is `IndexPath`?